# Will inner instructions always contain them all?

Tags: cpi, instructions, transaction-instructions

I'm basically trying to work out if there's any limit to inner instructions that would limit how much I can rely on them for understanding a transaction. I understand [from the docs](https://solana.com/docs/rpc/json-structures#inner-instructions) that a list of them can be returned for each transaction instruction.

So if I have a transaction that calls into program A at instruction index 0, and that program makes 2 CPI calls, there'd be two inner instructions.

Does this work recursively too? If I have programs A, B and C, and they call each other:

`A --CPI to-> B --CPI to-> C --CPI to-> token program transfer instruction`

Then if I call A in a transaction at index 0, will I get something like this?:

```
{
  index: 0,
  instructions: [
    {
      programIdIndex: // the one for B,
      accounts: //,
      data: //
    },
    {
      programIdIndex: // the one for C,
      accounts: //,
      data: //
    },
    {
      programIdIndex: // the one for token program,
      accounts: // token transfer accounts
      data: // token transfer data
    },
  ]
```

Assuming this does work, are there any limitations to this recursion, other than the existing limits of transaction size? Given there's no re-entrancy, are we able to always unroll inner instructions fully?

Comment: It does work recursively -- everything will be in `innerInstructions`

Answer (score 2):

There only limit is that the CPI depth is currently limited to 4:

https://solana.com/docs/programs/limitations#cpi-call-depth-calldepth-error

So your A->B->C->Transfer example is fine, but it's at max depth. It's pretty common to see something like:

```
A->B->Transfer
    ->Transfer Again
    ->Transfer Again
   B<-Return
A<-Return
```

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful! It makes me think that inner instructions should unroll them all, since the max depth is only 4.